# Change file name of image path in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, path

My image URL is like this:

```
photo\myFolder\image.jpg
```

I want to change it so it looks like this:

```
photo\myFolder\image-resize.jpg
```

Is there any short way to do it?

Comment: Your question doesn't say a lot. Why would String.Replace not work for you?

Comment: @zey Can't you use Find and Replace?

Comment: no , file type and file name may be dynamic :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) method.

> Returns the file name of the specified path string without the extension.

```
string path = @"photo\myFolder\image.jpg";
string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
string NewPath = path.Replace(file, file + "-resize");
Console.WriteLine(NewPath); //photo\myFolder\image-resize.jpg
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/MQx1bY).

Comment: If the path is `images\myFolder\image.jpg` your method will also change the `images`part of the path to `image-resizes`. I would get the directory path, the filename and the extension separately, change the filename and rebuild a path from all these elements.

Answer (score 27):

This following code snippet changes the filename and leaves the path and the extenstion unchanged:

```
public static string ChangeFilename(string filepath, string newFilename)
{
    // filepath = @"photo\myFolder\image.jpg";
    // newFileName = @"image-resize";

    string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath);    // @"photo\myFolder"
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filepath);        // @".jpg"

    return Path.Combine(dir, newFilename + ext); // @"photo\myFolder\image-resize.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use a method like this:

```
private static string GetFileNameAppendVariation(string fileName, string variation)
{
    string finalPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);

    string newfilename = String.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), variation, Path.GetExtension(fileName));

    return Path.Combine(finalPath, newfilename);
}
```

In this way:

```
string result = GetFileNameAppendVariation(@"photo\myFolder\image.jpg", "-resize");
```

Result: **photo\myFolder\image-resize.jpg**

Answer (score 3):

This is what i use for file renaming

```
public static string AppendToFileName(string source, string appendValue)
{
    return $"{Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(source), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(source))}{appendValue}{Path.GetExtension(source)}";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or the File.Move method:

```
System.IO.File.Move(@"photo\myFolder\image.jpg", @"photo\myFolder\image-resize.jpg");
```

---

BTW: \ is a relative Path and / a web Path, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 string  fileName = @"photo\myFolder\image.jpg";
 string newFileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.LastIndexOf('.')) + 
                     "-resize" + fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf('.'));

 File.Copy(fileName, newFileName);
 File.Delete(fileName);
```

Comment: File.Move would do your last 2 lines in one

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
File.Copy(Server.MapPath("~/") +"photo/myFolder/image.jpg",Server.MapPath("~/") +"photo/myFolder/image-resize.jpg",true);
File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/") + "photo/myFolder/image.jpg");
```